# Programmatically retrieve the .class files output location from Websphere using java

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, websphere

Currently, I am creating a plugin for eclipse. I need to access the compiled JSP(.class) files from my plugin and I am using the Websphere application server.  Is there any way to get the compiled JSP(.class) files location programmatically using java?

Answer (score 0):

You can access the location like this.

```
URL classesRootDir = getClass().getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation();
```

Comment: Is it possible to get the Websphere server RuntimeBaseDirectory path programmatically, which contains the compiled .class files of the JSP files?

Comment: This will get you the following directory relative to your project. ../MyApp/WEB-INF/classes/

Comment: You can check the following [link](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21232487) for the Websphere configuration

Comment: The thing is I don't have the class files and I need the location to access the generated class file's. Since the class files I need to access dynamically changes.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following from within the JSP:

```
ClassLoader.getSystemResource(this.getClass().getName().replace(".", "/").concat(".class"))
```

Comment: I need to get the path from my plugin without using any JSP's. Is it possible to access the server configurations and get the RuntimeBaseDirectory path which contains compiled .class files of JSP.